# How not to show a table if it's empty in Angular2

Tags: html, angular

I'm looking for a solution on how not to show my table if there is no data in it. I tried with `*ngIf` but it didn't work, maybe I did it wrong.

I don't think `[hidden]` is a good solution.

Here is my code :

```html
<div *ngIf="exceptions">
    <h1 class="applicationTitle">Exceptions</h1>

    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Timeslot</th>

        <tr *ngFor="#exception of exceptions">
            <td>{{exception.date}}</td>
            <td>{{exception.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `<tr *ngFor="#exception of exceptions">` is invalid Angular markup. It should be `<tr *ngFor="let exception of exceptions">`

Comment: Try `*ngIf="exceptions.length"`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Why is it invalid markup ? It's working fine with me ! If I do "let exception of exceptions", nothing is shown so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf`

```html
<table *ngIf="exceptions" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Timeslot</th>

    <tr *ngFor="let exception of exceptions">
        <td>{{exception.date}}</td>
        <td>{{exception.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Even when I do that, I got an error saying : "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined". I know it's undefined, it's because of that I don't want to display it

Comment: Sounds like you are using `.value` somewhere else in your code or `exceptions` contains `null` entries.

Comment: Please check where you are getting `null`.

Comment: No ok, that's my bad. Didn't look further than the tip of my nose. It's the morning sorry ! The problem come from my typescript code, where I need to put a if condition !

Comment: This will display the table if `exceptions` is an empty array.

Comment: You can also use `<table [hidden]="!!exceptions" ...>`. `*ngIf` removes it entirely from the DOM, `[hidden]` just sets visibility to `none` but keeps the elements in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngIf="exceptions.length > 0">
    <h1 class="applicationTitle">Exceptions</h1>

    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Timeslot</th>

        <tr *ngFor="#exception of exceptions">
            <td>{{exception.date}}</td>
            <td>{{exception.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

You just need to update your If condition that's all.

Comment: Tried it, got the same error than the first answer.. :(

Comment: @FlorianGuebel so you got the issue now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" *ngIf="exceptions.length > 0">
```

Keep in mind though `ngIf` will remove the element from the DOM, which might be an expensive operation if your table is really large. In that case you might be better of using `[hidden]` after all.